# AJAX and Laravel - load data dynamically on modal "Unexpected identifier"

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I'm am trying to load data dynamically on bootstrap modal with ajax, but I can not put it to work ye. I've done some research and I've seen some videos and still I can not do it. I hope someone can help me

```
                  <ul>
                  @foreach ($rs as $r)
                    <li><button class="viewData" value="view" id="{{$r->id}}">{{$r->title}}</button></li>
                  @endforeach
                  </ul>
```

this is my items

```
  <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="projectView" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content" id="modal-content">
                  <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-remodal-action="close">
                      <div class="lr">
                          <div class="rl">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                          <div class="modal-body" id="project-content">
                            <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

this is my modal where I want to show my item on detail

**UPDATE:**
I updated my js file and now I am trying to print the contents of my object in the modal but it giving me this error "Unexpected identifier"

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });


   $('.viewData').click(function(){
     var project_id = $(this).attr("id");


     $.ajax({
   url:"/data",
   method:"POST",
   data:{'project_id' : project_id},

   success:function(data){
     var htmlString = "";

     htmlString += "<h3 class="text-center">" + data.title + "</h3>";

     $('#project-content').html(htmlString);
     console.log(data);
     $('#projectView').modal("show");
   }
 });

   });

});
```

this is my js file where I pass the item id

```
  public function dataToModal(Request $request) {

  if(!empty($request)){
    $id = $request->project_id;
    $project = content::FindOrFail($id);

    return  Response::json($project);

 } else {
  return 'asa';
}

}
```

This is just a project I created to test this functionality, when it is working I will implement it on the main site. Someone can help me? Any help and suggestions are welcome!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please provide your controller code

Comment: controller code updated*

Comment: can't seem find the cause. this is a js error. you mind opening your browser console and check which line causes the error. you can click the console error at the right side, it will bring you to the code

Comment: Is supposed to be in line 22 which is  htmlString + =" <h3 class = "text-center"> "+ data.title +" </ h3> ";  But I think everything is fine. when I return my object data through console.log it gives me all the fields that I need. I dont understand why I cant just get the + data.title + for example.

Comment: well its wooorking now :) its just the class on h3 tag that must be between  ' ' instead of " " .. thanks for the comment *

Comment: no problem. sounds good

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
   $('.viewData').click(function(){
     var project_id = $(this).attr("id");

     $.ajax({
       url:"/data",
       method:"POST",
       data: {project_id : project_id},
       success:function(data){
         $('#project-content').html(data);
         console.log(data);
         $('#projectView').modal("show");
       }
     });
   });
});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function dataToModal(Request $request) {
 if(!empty($request)){
   $data = $request->all();
   //print_r($request->all());
   return $data;
 } else {
    return 'asa';
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer me, if I return $data it gives me an object like this "Object {1: null}1: null__proto__: Objectconstructor: function Object()" and still I cant get the id. I'm sure it's very simple to do but I'm not getting there, and I've tried to see examples but I still can not do it :(